# Pandas replace .apply(lambda x: with fast solution e.g. using numpy arrays

Tags: pandas, lambda, vectorization, apply, multi-index

I am trying to speed up a ranking function that I use to process millions of rows with hundreds of factors.  I have provided a sample MCVE below:

```
to_rank = ['var_1', 'var_2', 'var_3']
df = pd.DataFrame({'var_1' : np.random.randn(1000), 'var_2' : np.random.randn(1000), 'var_3' : np.random.randn(1000)})
df['date_id'] = np.random.choice(range(2001, 2012), df.shape[0])
df['category'] = ','.join(chr(random.randrange(97, 97 + 4 + 1)).upper() for x in range(1,df.shape[0]+1)).split(',')
```

My ranking code is below as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import bottleneck as bn

%timeit ranked = df[['date_id', 'category'] + to_rank].groupby(['date_id', 'category']).apply(lambda x: x[to_rank].apply(lambda x: bn.nanrankdata(x) * 100 / len(x) - 1))

10 loops, best of 3: 106 ms per loop
```

With my data, this takes about 30 - 40 seconds.  I gather that .apply(lambda x: has big overheads, including a loop, dtype detection, and shape analysis, and I am using this twice to loop over a multi-index, which is probably doubly inefficient.  I have read that one can vectorize this by using Series/numpy arrays (e.g. https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-4-performance.html but I am struggling to implement this myself; indeed, most similar questions about applying a function over a multi-index seem to use .apply(lambda x: so I suspect others could also benefit from speeding up their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function and use `transform`, although the time taken is not that much better (only twice as fast) :

```
def nanrankdata_len(x):
    return bn.nanrankdata(x)*100/len(x) - 1

%timeit ranked = df.groupby(['date_id','category']).transform(nanrankdata_len)
#-> 10 loops, best of 3: 55.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried this but failed.  Presumably faster because it supplies a Series rather than dataframe or something along those lines?

The fastest sorts of solutions I've seen elsewhere seem to have involved passing Series via multi-indexing.

Comment: Also I notice that this effectively removes one of the .apply(lambda x: calls, so looping over each column must be implied in transform which is helpful.